# Species identification please - Bug is a plague for Italian Stone Pines (Pinus Pinea)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

They hangout on the top of *Pinus pinea* and spray a sticky substance all over the place. Size is about 2mm (head and abdomen) may be 4mm including antennae and legs. Could you please help me identify it and understand some of its habits and biology? I took the photos in a coastal town in Southern Spain. Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's and aphid (Hemiptera:Sternorrycha). Most likely, it belongs to the genus *Cinara*, which is common on trees. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinara